# Scrolling issues in a form with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, events, scroll

I have a form, in that form has a split container.
In one of the panels there is a picturebox with an image.  I am increasing then decreasing the size of the picturebox (aka zooming the image) using the mouse wheel.  When the picturebox becomes bigger than the panels visible area it creates the V and H scroll bars, which is what I want.

The problem that I am running into is that the scroll bar is scrolling at the same time that my image is zooming, also sometimes the panels scrollbar is stealing my mousewheel events completely away from the picturebox and stops zooming the image.

Any suggestions on how I can grab the mouse wheel events and consume them completely without the scroll bar using them?

Comment: No-repro on Windows 7 & FW 3.5. `SplitContainer1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles SplitContainer1.MouseWheel` that resizes the picturebox only does resizing. Please post your code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: On second thoughts I think this is a focus issue. Set the focus to the PictureBox when it is entered.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml

Public Class Form1

  Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
    PictureBox1.Focus()
  End Sub

  Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    PictureBox1.Focus()
  End Sub
End Class
```